# Compressing an input stream Java

Tags: java, io, gzip

This honestly should not be having so many issues, but I must be missing something obvious.

I can compress a file just fine using `GZIPOutputStream` but when I try to get the input directly *(not from a file, but from a pipe or something)*, when I go to call gunzip -d on my file to see if it decompresses correctly, it tells me that it runs into an end of file immediately. Basically, I want these to work

```
echo foo | java Jgzip >foo.gz
```

or

```
java Jzip <test.txt >test.gz
```

And there's no guarantee these are strings, so we're reading **byte by byte**. I thought I could just use `System.in and System.out`, but that doesn't seem to working.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    try{
        BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        GZIPOutputStream gout = new GZIPOutputStream (System.out);

        while ((bytesRead = bf.read(buff)) != -1) {
            gout.write(buff,0,bytesRead);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IO error.");
        System.exit(-1);    
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Unexpected exception or error.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to the answers below, I would suggest using `System.err.println` for error messages otherwise, your error message will be written to the `gz` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
OutputStream gout= new GZIPOutputStream( System.out );
System.setOut( new PrintStream( gout ));              //<<<<< EDIT here
while(( bytesRead = bf.read( buff )) != -1 ) {
   gout.write(buff,0,bytesRead);
}
gout.close(); // close flush the last remaining bytes in the buffer stream
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that setOut is expecting a PrintStream while gout is an OutputStream.

Comment: Remove the `System.setOut(gout);` and give @Aubin the accept tick!

Comment: I would strongly advise not to use `System.setOut()` if you are planning to put this inside a library later.

Comment: new PrintStream() added. @Axel: you're right this kind of functionality (redirect in/out/err) doesn't take place into a library

Comment: Still unfortunately, gunzip is now complaining that the format has been violated. At least that's a step up from just EOF.

Comment: *facepalms* Ignore me. I forgot this server has about three different versions of gzip. I was using the wrong one. You guys are right. THanks a bunch and I feel really silly now

Comment: Still no need to call `setOut()` at all. I'd be really surprised if it didn't work when you remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the stream. Simply add `gout.close();` after the while loop to make it work:

```
axel@loro:~/workspace/Test/bin/tmp$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 axel axel 1328 Oct 27 10:49 JGZip.class
axel@loro:~/workspace/Test/bin/tmp$ echo "hallo" | java JGZip > test.gz
axel@loro:~/workspace/Test/bin/tmp$ ls -l
total 24
-rw-rw-r-- 1 axel axel 1328 Oct 27 10:49 JGZip.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 axel axel   26 Oct 27 10:49 test.gz
axel@loro:~/workspace/Test/bin/tmp$ gzip -d test.gz 
axel@loro:~/workspace/Test/bin/tmp$ ls -l
total 24
-rw-rw-r-- 1 axel axel 1328 Oct 27 10:49 JGZip.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 axel axel    6 Oct 27 10:49 test
axel@loro:~/workspace/Test/bin/tmp$ cat test
hallo
```